# Detecting bump motion

Tags: ios, swift, cmmotionmanager

I'm trying to detect when the entire left side of an iPhone is bumped. Here's what I have so far:

```
let manager = CMMotionManager()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if manager.deviceMotionAvailable {
        manager.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = 0.02
        manager.startDeviceMotionUpdatesToQueue(NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) {
            [weak self] (data: CMDeviceMotion!, error: NSError!) in
            if data.userAcceleration.x > 2 {
                // Perform action
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The code above works as long as I bump the top left corner of the phone. However, if I try to bump the entire phone directly to the left in a straight line, it rarely if ever works. Is there something I'm missing here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if data.userAcceleration.x > 2 {
            // Perform action
        }
```

Make 2, say 1.5 or smaller, because 2 requires a really fast acceleration.

Comment: Changing it to 1 did the trick. May have to adjust it a bit, but it's a huge improvement. Thanks!

Comment: What about if you want a shake and a bump motion?